# Regex semi optional

Tags: .net, regex

This regex is close to what I want:

```
(?i)(?<=\b(subject|title):?)[^:].+?$
```

I have these examples:

- `subject:water front condo`
- `subject: water front condo`
- `subject water front condo`
- `subjectwater front condo`

With my current regex, all examples return `water front condo`.

I don't want the last example to match. How can I require a space if a `:` is not present?

I'm on .NET version 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for *alternation*, `|`, *i.e.* one or the other:

```
(?i)(?<=\b(subject|title)(:| ))[^:].+?$
                         ^^^^^
```

IMO though, you don't need to use the lookbehind, as you can just as well do:

```
(?i)\b(subject|title)(:|\s)\s*.+?$
```

Comment: Ended up with (?i)(?<=\b(subject|title|re:)(:|\s)).+?$.  I was making it harder than it was.  I need the lookbehind to not capture.

Comment: You can make a group not capture by adding a `?:` at the beginning, like this: `(?i)(?:\b(subject|title|re:)(:|\s)).+?$`.

Comment: You two are talking about different kinds of capturing. Blam is talking about the whole regex capturing whatever it matches, into capture group 0. acheong87 is talking about the capture of parts of the regex in `()` – capture groups 1, 2, etc. Both methods work, but require slightly different code to extract the match. In this situation, I think acheong87's method will be easier.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane - Ah, I didn't perceive that possibility. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With a space, the last doest match
(?i)(?<=\b(subject|title):?)[ ^:].+?$

Comment: Problem is "subject: water front condo" now matches to ": water front condo".  It does not drop the :